# How to not submit a form if you have a duplicate ID already in the database table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I'm trying to create a Customer Form where you create a new customer with ID, Name, Address, Phone to add to the database. I want to check the database to make sure that the Customer ID that I enter in doesn't already exist, and if it does, just throw an error and prevent the page from submitting.

How would I go about doing that?

I tried doing a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT cust_id FROM customer ORDER BY cust_id desc";
```

So this orders the numbers from the Last to the First, and then I placed this as my value inside of the input tag for my text box:

```
value="<?= $row[0] + 1?>"
```

And this adds one on to the previous number, so it won't be a previous number entered in, but the user can still change the number. I don't want to disable the text because then I am unable to grab the number and insert it to the table.

Any help would be great!

Comment: love me some auto_increemnt primary id https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Where are the customerids coming from, that you can't simply generate them programmatically? Do you need to allow the user to edit the customerid?

Comment: Why would you want to do this!!????!

Comment: create auto_increment PK like @Dagon said. Let us know how it works

Answer (score 0):

Generate your cust_id, then tuck it away safely in `$_SESSION`. You can then display it on the form as static text and don't have to worry about the user changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. use the [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function to generate IDs for customers. If you need the ids to be numeric, you can use it with the [hex()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) function to get numeric ids. For example, `$cust_id = hex(uniqid());`.
2. Use autoincremental id on your SQL table, that way you don't need to generate ids during `INSERT`s.

**Note**: For both cases the id column should be unique, that way you will always get errors if there's an attempt to insert a duplicate id. Also, I'll take option 2 if I were you.